Mixing flow has aperiodic orbit?
Let $X$ be a compact connected metric space with more than one point.
Suppose that $H:X\times [0,\infty)\to X$ is continuous such that $h_0=H\restriction X\times \{0\}$ is the identity on $X$, and $h_{t+s}=h_{t}\circ h_{s}$ for all $t,s\in [0,\infty)$. Thus $H$ is a flow on $X$. Note that every $h_t$ is a homeomorphism.
Suppose further that $H$ is mixing: For every non-empty open set $U\subset X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $R$ such that $h_r[U]$ is $\varepsilon$-dense (in the Hausdorff metric sense) for all $r\geq R$.
Question. Must $H$ necessarily have an aperiodic orbit? That is, does there exist $x\in X$ such that $h_t(x)\neq h_s(x)$ for all $s\neq t$?

Take any point whose forward orbit is dense (such points are residual). If such an orbit is not aperiodic, then its orbit is compact. But $X$ is the closure of this orbit, so $X$ is equal to this orbit. So we have a continuous bijection from the circle to $X$, so $X$ is homeomorphic to the circle. And there are no mixing flows on the circle.

@VilleSalo This was my thinking also, but I did not realize $X$ would have to be a circle. Why could it not be something like a figure 8? Is this because of the linearity property $h_{t+s}=h_{t}\circ h_{s}$?

@VilleSalo Also do you know if a mixing flow can have a fixed point of $X$?

It can't be an 8 because if an orbit intersects itself then you have found a period. I'm sure a mixing flow can have a fixpoint, but I'm off work now.

suspend a full shift / dilate time to get mixing / quotient an orbit
